# To implement Google Place Autocomplete API, Is session_token mandatory?

Tags: autocomplete, google-places-api, uuid

I want to use The places autocomplete API for implementing search easily. As per the billing documentation of Google, it is said that if session_token is not defined then the billing will be done independently.

My questions are:
1. Is it better to use the session_token method for autocomplete rather than independent method.

2. If yes, then it says using UUID 4 for session_token passing mechanism, I'd like to know how to use that on frontend.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you implementing your own autocomplete widget or use built-in `google.maps.Autocomplete`?

Comment: i want to use google places autocomplete.

Comment: There are two options: use `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` class or implement your own widget using `google.maps.places.PlacesService`. If you use the first one, session token is already created for you, you shouldn't implement it. If you use the second one, you should implement session tokens. Can you confirm that you are using the second approach and use JavaScript for development?

Comment: I'm using google.maps.places.Autocomplete class with JQuery for development. Is it better approach?

Comment: In this case session token is created automatically by API. You shouldn't implement nothing.